# Vim is taking 700MB memory on WIndows, how can I debug it?

Tags: windows, vim

I have Vim on Windows server 2012, and when I start it from the start menu everything works fine.  However, when I start it from the command line it take 5 seconds and uses 700MB memory.  Even when its not opening a file.  There is something weird going on, and I was wondering if there are any ways to debug it/figure out what is causing this?  Thanks, Eric.

EDIT:

**Here is the result of vim --startuptime outputfile (abbreviated):**

times in msec

clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script

clock   elapsed:              other lines

000.000  000.000: --- VIM STARTING ---

...

016.000  016.000: parsing arguments

016.000  000.000: expanding arguments

4794.000  4778.000: shell init

4794.000  000.000: Termcap init

...

4825.000  000.000: setting raw mode

8768.000  3943.000: start termcap

8768.000  000.000: clearing screen

8783.000  000.000: --- VIM STARTED ---

Comment: `<!-- insert flamewar below about how Emacs is superior to Vim -->`

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, I am yet to see anyone use Emacs on Windows.

Comment: Can you run `vim --startuptime outputfile`. This will time the startup and tell you where it is taking a long time.

Comment: It takes your shell almost 5 seconds to initialize. (Also just post the whole thing in a code block)

Comment: What is shell init actually calling?  I am running in a customized shell, but running a straight cmd runs quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Sysinternals' Process Explorer to check if any of the processes are starting child processes or if there is any difference in the environmental variables.

Also, Sysinternals' Procmon would allow you to check what registry entries, files, etc does any application use (filter by `command name` `includes` `vim`), but probably you will find the differences just with Process Explorer.

Sysinternals was a company that created some nice apps for Windows and Microsoft bought it some years ago. You can access the last version of any of their apps on http://live.sysinternals.com

Answer (score 0):

[Excerpt from Vim FAQ 2.5](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5):

```
2.5. I have a "xyz" (some) problem with Vim. How do I determine it is a
     problem with my setup or with Vim?  / Have I found a bug in Vim?

First, you need to find out, whether the error is in the actual runtime
files or any plugin that is distributed with Vim or whether it is a
simple side effect of any configuration option from your .vimrc or
.gvimrc. So first, start vim like this: 

    vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE

this starts Vim in nocompatible mode (-N), without reading your viminfo
file (-i NONE), without reading any configuration file (-u NONE for not
reading .vimrc file and -U NONE for not reading a .gvimrc file) or even
plugin.

In this invocation, try to reproduce your problem. If the error
persists, the chance is good you've found a bug in Vim (see also
Question 2.6. faq-2.6)

If the error does not occur when starting Vim this way, then the problem
is either related to some plugin of yours or some setting in one of your
local setup files. You need to find out, what triggers the error, you
try starting Vim this way: 

    vim -u NONE -U NONE -N

If the error occurs, the problem is your .viminfo file. Simply delete
the viminfo file then. If the error does not occur, try: 

    vim -u ~/.vimrc --noplugin -N -i NONE

This will simply use your .vimrc as configuration file, but not load any
plugins. If the error occurs this time, the error is possibly caused by
some configuration option inside your .vimrc file. Depending on the
length of your vimrc file, it can be quite hard to trace the origin
within that file.

The best way is to add :finish command in the middle of your .vimrc.
Then restart again using the same command line. If the error still
occurs, the bug must be caused because of a setting in the first half of
your .vimrc. If it doesn't happen, the problematic setting must be in
the second half of your .vimrc. So move the :finish command to the
middle of that half, of which you know that triggers the error and move
your way along, until you find the problematic option.
```

It also mentions how to create a log file:

```
You can also use the -V command line argument to get more debug
information to analyze the problem: 

    $ vim -V2logfile

You can increase the value passed to the -V argument to get more debug
information. By also specifying a logfile name, this makes sure, the
debug messages don't appear on the screen and won't disturb you when
trying to reproduce the problem.
```

Comment: So I tried vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE, and it still uses at least 700MB of memory.  Somehow I don't think it's a bug with vim though because 5 days ago this wasn't happening and I didn't just install or upgrade vim.  The log file is also blank when running vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE, and uninteresting when run normally.

Comment: Then I'd check if the executable you call from the start menu is the same called from the command line. Another point that could be related is the starting directory, which can be checked with `:pwd`.